# Problems with nginx vhost-database script

Tags: linux, ubuntu

## I new to scripting and struggling hard to understand and learn it. I'm having a problem with the script, when ever I tried to delete a subdomain I get error about unable to delete the database. Some variable problems I think Please help.

#!/bin/bash

## Delete Everything

set -e

## Colours

red=$'\e[1;31m'
grn=$'\e[1;32m'
yel=$'\e[1;33m'
blu=$'\e[1;34m'
mag=$'\e[1;35m'
cyn=$'\e[1;36m'
end=$'\e[0m'

## Variables.

domain=$1
db=$2
domain2=$3
userdb1=$4
userdb2=$5
sitesEnable='/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/'
sitesAvailable='/etc/nginx/sites-available/'
domainRegex="^[a-zA-Z0-9]"

## Check if you are root

if [ "$(whoami)" != 'root' ]; then
echo "You have no permission to run $0 as non-root user. Use sudo"
exit 1;
fi

## Ask the user to add domain name

while true
do
clear

echo ""
echo "${grn}Press [CTRL + C] to cancel...${end}"
echo ""
echo "Here all the domain on you server"
echo ""
echo "*************"
echo "${blu}"
ls -I default -I phpmyadmin -I filemanager -1 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
echo "${end}*************"

```
echo ""
echo "${yel}Please note, all data on your domain will be gone, proceed will caution!${end}"
echo ""
read -p ${grn}"Please provide domain to be deleted: ${end}: " domain
read -p ${grn}"Please type your domain one more time${end}: " domain2
echo
[ "$domain" = "$domain2" ] && break
echo "Domain you provide does not match, please try again!"
read -p "${grn}Press [Enter] key to continue...${end}" readEnterKey
```

done

until [[ $domain =~ $domainRegex ]]
do
echo -n "Enter valid domain: "
read domain
done

## Check if domain is not there

FILE=/etc/nginx/sites-available/$domain
file2=/var/www/$domain
if [ -f "$FILE" ] || [ -f "$file2" ] ; then
clear
else
echo ""
echo "$domain does not exist, please try again"
exit;
fi

clear

## Delete Database

domainClear=${domain//./}
domainClear2=${domainClear//-/}
mariadb <<MYSQL_SCRIPT
DROP DATABASE database_$domainClear2;
DROP USER 'user_$domainClear2'@'localhost';
MYSQL_SCRIPT
clear

## Delete domain.

rm -fr /var/www/$domain
unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/$domain
rm -f /etc/nginx/sites-available/$domain
rm -f /var/log/nginx/$domain.error.log
rm -f /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/$domain.conf

## Delete ssl.

rm -rf /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/$domain.conf /etc/letsencrypt/archive/$domain
rm -rf /etc/ssl/$domain
service nginx reload

## Delete Cache.

rm -rf /etc/nginx/mycache/$domain

```
systemctl reload nginx
clear
echo ""
```

echo ""

echo ""
echo "Domain $domain has been successfuly deleted along with database and SSL!"
rm -f /root/delete.sh
exit

Comment: Have you configured proper user in MariaDB that can do the operation you want?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I created subdomain along with the database properly. I used the following script to creat vhost and database.

#!/bin/bash

## Add Subdomain + Create Database

set -e

## Colours

red=$'\e[1;31m'
grn=$'\e[1;32m'
yel=$'\e[1;33m'
blu=$'\e[1;34m'
mag=$'\e[1;35m'
cyn=$'\e[1;36m'
end=$'\e[0m'
red="\e[0;91m"
blue="\e[0;94m"
expand_bg="\e[K"
blue_bg="\e[0;104m${expand_bg}"
red_bg="\e[0;101m${expand_bg}"
green_bg="\e[0;102m${expand_bg}"
green="\e[0;92m"
white="\e[0;97m"
yellow="\e[0;33m"
purple="\e[1;35m"
bold="\e[1m"
uline="\e[4m"
reset="\e[0m"

## Check if you are root

if [ "$(whoami)" != 'root' ]; then
echo "You have no permission to run $0 as non-root user. Use sudo"
exit 1;
fi

## Variables

domain=$1
domain2=$3
sitesEnable='/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/'
sitesAvailable='/etc/nginx/sites-available/'
domainRegex="^[a-zA-Z0-9]"

## Ask the user to add domain name

while true
do

clear

```
echo ""
```

echo "${grn}Press [CTRL + C] to cancel...${end}"
echo ""

read -p ${grn}"Please provide your domain plus subdomain name [eg, forum.domain.com]${end}: " domain
read -p ${grn}"Please type your domain plus subdomain name one more time${end}: " domain2
echo
[ "$domain" = "$domain2" ] && break
echo "Domain you provide does not match, please try again!"
read -p "${grn}Press [Enter] key to continue...${end}" readEnterKey
done

until [[ $domain =~ $domainRegex ]]
do
echo -n "Enter valid domain: "
read domain
done

## Check if domain already added

if [ -e $sitesAvailable$domain ]; then
echo "This domain already exists. Please delete your domain from the main menu options and try again"
exit;
fi

## Check if domain already added var www

if [ -e /var/www/$domain ]; then
echo "This domain already exists. Please delete your domain from the main menu options and try again"
exit;
fi

#### CREATE DATABASE

echo -n "Type the name for your database [eg, database_domain], followed by [ENTER]: "
read DB

#check if database is exist
DATABASE=/var/lib/mysql/$DB
if [ -e $DATABASE ]; then
echo ""
echo "$DB does exist in the database already, please try again"
exit;
else
echo ""
fi

echo -n "Type the username for your database [eg, user_domain], followed by [ENTER]: "
read USR

echo ""
echo -n "Type the password for your new user [eg, password123!@#_domain], followed by [ENTER]: "
read PASS

mysql -uroot <<MYSQL_SCRIPT
CREATE DATABASE $DB;
CREATE USER '$USR'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$PASS';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $DB.* TO '$USR'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
MYSQL_SCRIPT

## Add Domain to the server

mkdir /var/www/$domain

## Install ssl

mkdir -p /etc/ssl/$domain/
cd /etc/ssl/$domain/
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -out $domain.csr -keyout $domain.key -subj "/C=US/ST=Rhode Island/L=East Greenwich/O=Fidelity Test/CN=$domain"
openssl x509 -req -days 36500 -in $domain.csr -signkey $domain.key -out $domain.crt
service nginx reload

## Add html file to the domain

if ! echo "domain has been added!" > /var/www/$domain/index.html
then
echo "There is an ERROR create index.html file"
exit;
else
echo "index.html has been created successfully"
fi
chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/$domain
nginx -t
systemctl reload nginx
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/$domain
systemctl restart php7.4-fpm.service
systemctl restart nginx

## Add Cache to the server

mkdir -p /etc/nginx/mycache/$domain

## Add nginx Vhost for domain

configName=$domain
cd $sitesAvailable
wget vhost-fastcgi -O $domain
sed -i "s/domain.com/$domain/g" $sitesAvailable$configName

## PHP POOL SETTING

wget -q $php7_dotdeb -O /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/$domain.conf
sed -i "s/domain.com/$domain/g" /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/$domain.conf
echo "" >> /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/$domain.conf
dos2unix /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/$domain.conf > /dev/null 2>&1
service php7.4-fpm reload

ln -s $sitesAvailable$configName $sitesEnable$configName
nginx -t
systemctl reload nginx

## Restart nginx and php-fpm

echo "Restart Nginx & PHP-FPM ..."
echo ""
sleep 1
systemctl restart nginx
systemctl restart php7.4-fpm.service
clear

## Success Prompt

echo ""

echo "Complete! Your new $domain subdomain has been added!"
echo " Please save the following information."
echo "MySQL user created."
echo "Database:   $DB"
echo "Username:   $USR"
echo "Password:   $PASS"
echo ""

echo ""
#rm -f /root/domain3.sh
exit

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried the suggested edit but its the same thing. I think the problem is with the Delete Domain variable. ... :  # Delete Database
domainClear=${domain//./}
domainClear2=${domainClear//-/}
mariadb <<MYSQL_SCRIPT
DROP DATABASE database_$domainClear2;
DROP USER 'user_$domainClear2'@'localhost';
MYSQL_SCRIPT
=================================  Its still looking for example: wp_forum.example.com ......... Please help. I would highly appreciate that.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When I used the above script to create vshot and database, I get the proper out put as follows.

Complete! Your new test.example.com subdomain has been added!

Please save the following information.
MySQL user created.
Database:   test_db
Username:   test_user
Password:   test24689